# Alert from Empty cells to users

Tags: google-apps-script

It is possible to send by email **only the empty cells**  from the active sheet, within a specific range?
The goal is alert the users to update their info. Thanks.﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can collect the info on the empty cells by the code below. After you are collecting the information to an object you can use the MailApp in order to send an email with these data.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
  // check if the cell is empty
  if (data[i][1] == ''){  
    // collect this info into an object.
  }
}

// send an email with the cells
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Comment: Hi Ido, this function works, but I want only display the users with empty fields.

example: I've got a sheet with at least 40 users, with data (email, name, etc), and want only to send by email the users with at least one unfilled cell, not all the data from the SS.

The users with all the their complete data, must not appear.

Is there a way to do this filter by a defined Range?

Thanks!